# Real-time deduplication strategy for relational DB

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concurrency, relational-database, deadlock

I have a messages table with some fields like `id`, `version`, `timestamp`

I'm trying to insert and retrieve messages with real-time deduplication logic, implemented in stored procedures.

- On insert, if a message with given `id` already exists in the table, I invoke a complex deduplication logic (a number of IF/ELSE statements) and then update messages's `version`, `timestamp`, etc. Otherwise I insert a new row.
- On retrieve, I search for the oldest message and not just select it, but also update a few fields (changing state, setting transient_token, etc)

The problem is, **it does not work as fast as I need**: ~ 200 rps on insert and the same on retrieve

Separately my stored procedures work good, but when I execute both of them concurrently, they start fighting for locks under load > 30 rps, performance dramatically decreases and deadlocks appear periodically

**Are there some best practices to solve my problem?** I feel that the whole approach sucks, not my concrete implementation.

May be I should use some temp buffer table for all incoming messages and perform dedup logic afterwords? I would appreciate any ideas.

* I can't use nosql DB in my case (management decision), I need to gain max performance with Mysql/MariaDb